# A rejected or deleted iPhone app binary was approved and released - New iTunes Connect issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

On this month, soon after new iTunes Connect was available, I added a new version of my app.
But right after submitting for review, the app was rejected due to invalid binary error.

So, I rejected(deleted) the binary myself and built the app again without modification but adding +1 to the built number.
And I uploaded the binary using Xcode 5 and submitted for review again.
And about 10 days later, it was approved.

But a problem happened.
The build number of the app I downloaded from the App Store was the build number which was rejected due to invalid binary.
I checked iTunes Connect now, but the selected binary is the 2nd binary which I uploaded after the app was rejected.

Fortunately, the 1st binary which was rejected but released unexpectedly is working properly.
But I'm now submitting another next version of the app.

And this time, I don't want the same issue to happen again.

Is the issue still happening now?
Did you experience the same issue in the new iTunes Connect when you rejected a binary and uploaded another binary like me?

Comment: did you upload the first version to itune using Xcode lower version then 5?

Comment: @Retro No, I uploaded both of the binary using Xcode 5.1.1.

Comment: I guess it really confusing, may be you should drop a mail to apple support about your issue and they could explain what was behind this. Then you will be sure to go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted another new version of an app after I posted the question.

And I rejected the binary of it once myself.
And this time, just in case, to avoid the same issue, I changed not only build number (`CFBundleVersion`) of the app but also the version number (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) of the app.
(The last time, I only changed the build number.)


And a week later, the new version was approved.
And the version number and build number was correct. This means the same issue did not happen.

I don't know that changing only build number (`CFBundleVersion`) causes the issue. 
But I recommend that you change version number (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) as well as the build number (`CFBundleVersion`) when you re-upload your binary to the iTunes Connect.